# Vector addition is equivalent to multiplying by what matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Square matrices are nice objects to work with. Consider two vectors $b$ and $c$ and their sum with $b$ not identically the 0 vector.

What matrix $A$ acting on $b$ is equivalent to $b + c$? Or otherwise, $b + c = Ab$?

I tried this with a 2x2 matrix of four unknowns and it didn't seem to admit a system of equations that was solvable. Perhaps the assumption that $A$ is diagonal is sufficient.

Comment: Consider the case $b=0$ to see that no such matrix exists for general $c$.

Comment: Interesting to note, but is that the *only* such case?

Comment: Translation by a nonzero vector is not a linear operation, but it is affine. A typical way around this in computer graphics, for instance, is to work with matrices in one dimension higher. See e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) on Wikipedia.

Comment: So there's this odd workaround where, to represent translation via matrices, you add another dimension and put a $1$ there?

Comment: Yes. I don't know that it's odd, it's extremely convenient.

Answer (score 5):

The function $T:b\mapsto Ab$ is *linear* on $b$. In particular, $T(0)=0$. Therefore no such matrix can exist.

---

The transformation $\rho_c(b)=b+c$, also known as translation by $c$, is an *affine* transformation. [Affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations) are occasionally described by a matrix, too. But then we need an extra coordinate, augmenting the vector $b=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ to $\tilde{b}=(b_1,\ldots,b_n,1)$. The effect of affine transformations can be described on the collection of augmented vectors using an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$-matrices. Here
$$
\widetilde{\rho_c(b)}=(b_1+c_1,\ldots,b_n+c_n,1)^T
=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&0&\cdots&0&c_1\\
0&1&\cdots&0&c_2\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&1&c_n\\
0&0&\cdots&0&1
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
b_1\\ b_2\\ \vdots\\ b_n\\1
\end{array}\right).
$$
That is, an $n\times n$ identity block augmented by the column vector $\tilde{c}$.

---

This way of writing an affine transformation has been useful for example in 3D computer graphics engines (what I learned when programming in DOS-era, I'm not up to speed, but this should still apply). Often transformations (translations and rotations mostly) between several coordinate systems need to be used together and composed. The need for affine transformations comes from the fact that not all those coordinate systems share the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

As particular solution, for $b_i \neq 0$ we have that the following trivially works

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{b_1+c_1}{b_1}& 0 & \ldots & 0\\ 0 & \frac{b_2+c_2}{b_2}&\ldots&0 \\0&0&\ldots&0\\ \cdots & \cdots &\cdots &\cdots\\0&0&\ldots&\frac{b_n+c_n}{b_n}\end{pmatrix}$$

and for $b_1 \neq 0$ also this one

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}\frac{b_1+c_1}{b_1}& 0 & \ldots & 0\\ \frac{b_2+c_2}{b_1} & 0&\ldots&0 \\\frac{b_3+c_3}{b_1}&0&\ldots&0\\ \cdots & \cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\\frac{b_n+c_n}{b_1}&0&\ldots&0\end{pmatrix}$$

trivially works but, as pointed out in comments and other answers, no general solution exists.

---

To see why such matrix doesn't exist in general, let assume $b\neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$ then given $Ab =b+c$ by linearity we have

$$A(2b) =2Ab =2(b+c) \neq 2b+c$$

Comment: The same matrix is supposed to work for all vectors $b$.

Comment: No of course, I want to show some possible particular solution since in the comments MartinR already pointed out that general solution doesn’t exist. Now I see also yor general discussion. I clarify better that point. Thanks

Comment: Your answer does not explain that.

Comment: I’ve clarified now that these are only very special cases not solving the problem in general. Thanks

Comment: I've also added a small proof by a simple counterexample. Thanks again to have pointed out this lack in the explanation.